# java singleton of parameterized class

Tags: java, singleton, design-patterns, parameterized

I can't get this disentangled.

```
public class MySingleton<T extends AUsefulClass>{
    Map<String, T> myUsefulRegistry;
    private static MySingleton<T> _instance = null;

    public static instance(){
        if(instance == null)
            _instance = new MySingleton<T>();

        return _instance;
    }
}

public class Test{
    @Test
    public void testThis(){
        MySingleton<SomeClass> mySingleton = MySingleton<SomeClass>().instance();
    }
}
```

This parametrization is faulty because you cannot make a static reference to a nonstatic T. Still, I would like to build a parameterizable singleton class.

Comment: Why do you need a singleton? Give us more information.

Comment: I need just one instance of one flavour in a runtime, but there are multiple possible flavours which can be decided on instantiation.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in Java (unlike .NET) you've only got one static variable no matter how many different type arguments you provide - so `MySingleton<Foo>._instance` is equal to `MySingleton<Bar>._instance`.

I suspect you want a `Map<Class<? extends AUsefulClass>, MySingleton>`, suppressing the warnings about raw types. Then you'd make your `instance` method take a `Class<T>` parameter as well, so it would know what to look up.

Of course, this is assuming you want separate state for different type arguments. If you *don't* need different state for `MySingleton<Foo>` and `MySingleton<Bar>` you can truly have a single instance, and just cast it while suppressing the unchecked conversion warning.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton instance;

    private final Map<String, ?> myUsefulRegistry;

    private <T> MySingleton(Class<T> type) {
        myUsefulRegistry = new HashMap<String, T>();
    }

    public static <T> MySingleton getInstance(Class<T> type) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MySingleton(type);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

If you are planning on reassigning `myUsefulRegistry`, you will obviously have to omit the *final* modifier and also implement state based on the `type` parameter (by storing it to use again).

*Edit*: There's an issue if the user passes a different type to the original. You may want to store the type in any case then, so you can check whether any proceeding calls to `getInstance(Class<T>)` are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather look at my design in this case. Also, if you want to create a different singleton due circumstances. You'd probably use a factory to instantiate the singleton at first.

I'm not sure if the singleton pattern is a good approach, it introduces global state via objects, which is the very thing you probably don't want.